# How to trigger a process quarterly/monthly using declarative methods

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

How can I achieve a use case such as creating quarterly reports using declarative methods?

I went through the following article (https://medium.com/@idanblich/create-monthly-records-using-flow-aac1824e9382), but did not grasp the idea behind it.

**UPDATE:**

Is something like the following alright? Will the following keep running forever? I have a feeling it might have unexpected consequences though.

[image]

**Another solution:**

[Creating quarterly records using Flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297280/creating-quarterly-records-using-flow)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using something like Doug Ayers' [Mass Action Scheduler](https://douglascayers-org.github.io/sfdx-mass-action-scheduler/). Whilst you need the code to make it work, it then allows data-driven configuration of what processes to execute and against what schedule.

Comment: Thanks @Phil for the reference.